# Removing items from nested forms inserts instead of delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cocoon-gem

I'm currently using cocoon rails gem to create nested forms.

The problem happens when I edit the "father" entity and remove some nested items, it adds another one instead of removing it. I created a gist file that explains it better with ruby on rails console logs. Here it is: https://gist.github.com/msmosso/310835bbb1a4b7cfe1a9.

Thanks for advance.
Cheers!

Comment: Please show us some code. I would especially need the view and controller code to be able to say something sensible.

Comment: Here comes the code: https://gist.github.com/msmosso/6c48fb2cd0117ad43f31. It contains the form, the nested fields partial, clients controller and client and store models.

Comment: That's all your code? I see no immediate mistake or explanation for the behaviour you describe. Can you make a minimal rails project with this error and put it on github and send me the link? The code as shown should just work imho.

Comment: For sure. The page in question is /clientes/novo: https://github.com/msmosso/cocoon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `client_params` you specify which parameters are allowed for a client, and a nested store. You did not specify the `:id` for a store, and that makes sure that each time a client is saved, it will be stored as a new one. So the fix is actually pretty simple:

```
def client_params
  params.require(:client).permit(:name, stores_attributes: [:id, :client_id, :name, :name2, :district, :address, :number, :complement, :cnpj, :city_id, :mail, :obs, :status, :phone, :phone2, :phone3, :sversion, :_destroy])
end
```

I did not see that until I tried it, doh!

So: I added `:id` and removed `:created_at` and `:updated_at` (the last two are not really relevant, but you do not want those in that list).

Answer (score 0):

Does the answer to this question help?

[Cannot destroy existing nested association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621013/cannot-destroy-existing-nested-association)

Specifically the part about allow_destroy.  Deleting through the update action seems fairly irregular.  Perhaps something is wired up incorrectly.

Comment: I already have allow_destroy, here comes my Client model: https://gist.github.com/msmosso/8a69e582ecdeb6813058

Comment: I also allowed _destroy as you can see here: https://gist.github.com/msmosso/1b42a62d1e1f21843cc7